# Alert doesn't pop up when expected

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I want to change a label's text.

```
@IBAction func renameLabel(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let labelTextToBeChanged = "some text"
        let changedLabelText = changeLabeltext(text: labelTextToBeChanged!)
        // Do something
        print("changedLabelText: \(changedLabelText)")
}
```

The function changeLabeltext() contains an alert controller, as shown below.
I expect that after the call of changeLabeltext(text: labelTextToBeChanged!) an alert window pops up and that after modifying the text the new text ist assigned to changedLabelText and is printed out.
However, after the function call an empty text ist printed out and then, after exit the IBAction function, the alert window pops up. What I am doing wrong?

```
func changeLabeltext(text: String) -> String{
    var inputTextField:UITextField?

    // Create the controller
    let alertController = UIAlertController(
        title: "Ändere Projekt- oder Versionsname",
        message: "",
        preferredStyle: .alert)

    // Create a textfield for input
    alertController.addTextField{
        (textField: UITextField!) -> Void in
        textField.placeholder = text
        inputTextField = textField
    }

    // Create the actions
    let saveAction = UIAlertAction(
        title: "Speichern",
        style: .default,
        handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
            inputTextField = alertController.textFields![0]
            inputTextField?.text = text
    })

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(
        title: "Abbruch",
        style: .default,
        handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
    })

    // Add the actions to the UIAlertController
    alertController.addAction(saveAction)
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

    present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    return (inputTextField?.text)!
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`inputTextField` is empty when this line is executed `return (inputTextField?.text)!`. All you have to do is change your `saveAction`, and from that action you coud use the text:

```
let saveAction = UIAlertAction(
    title: "Speichern",
    style: .default,
    handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
        inputTextField = alertController.textFields![0]
        inputTextField?.text = text
        use(newText: text) //Or do whatever you want with the text
})
```

and declare the function that uses that text:

```
func use(NewText: String) {
//Do whatever with the new text
}
```

And there is no need to return a string from `changeLabeltext`:

```
func changeLabeltext(text: String) {
//...
}
```

Comment: I need the changed string outside the alert function and inside the calling IBAction. Why is the alert not directly performed after the call before the print statement, but only after the IBAction is left? The print statement never gets the changed text.

Comment: @HeinzM. I would recommend having another function use `text`. See the updated answer.

Comment: @HeinzM. did you try the answer i provided which does exactly that?

Comment: please do all UI operations with Main thread only.
ie, DispathchQueue.main.async {
//write the code whatever you want to execute
}

Comment: @RakeshaShastri yes I did. However the cancel action fails, as already was mentioned  by Carpsen90.

Comment: @HeinzM. what does fail mean? that closure won't be executed that's all. Why would you want the it to when you click cancel?